# How can I sync video and audio in real time with the primitive Media Foundation APIs?

Tags: c#, audio, video, c++-cli, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to sync Audio and Video into a presentation using the **Primitive Media Foundation Interfaces**: `IMFSourceReader`; `EVR`; `SAR`. I've tried some techniques and yet Audio is ahead of Video.

To summarize the structure of playback of Video and Audio: I have **two buffers** (Audio and Video) that hold 6 samples each, each sample processed, plus one is requested from `IMFSourceReader`. Each type (Audio or Video) contains its **TASK** for processing buffer samples.
The presentation clock, according to **MSDN**, is good to use SAR to **improve synchronization**, and that's what I'm doing here.

Attempt implemented for synchronization: To try to display the video at the correct time, I am performing a delay that I calculated as follows:

```
//Calculates the Media Frame Rate. The Numerator and Denominator were obtained from IMFMediaType from the video file loaded locally by IMFSourceReader.
var FrameRate = Math.Round((Numerator / Denominator)).

//Calculates the delay that will be used to call the next sample. Video processing time is 8 to 11ms.
var Delay = Math.Round((1000 - Video Sample Processing Time) / FrameRate) - 12.
```

**Video sample processing time** = + or - 10ms.

The subtracted value from every division (**-12**) is because if I implemented the resulting delay value, the video would crash. In my tests, what is possible to perceive to human eyes, about 13ms, was the best result that I achieved in sync with Audio. It starts well, but it falls behind in relation to Audio.

I don't have much to show code. But I'll show you how I'm trying to play the media loaded from a local file.

## Video Processing Task:

```
//Get the next video sample available in the buffer.
IMFSample VideoSample = BufferVideo.Next();

//Calls the method that will copy the read sample data to the IMFVideoSampleAllocator sample. The sample is accessed for the IMF2DBuffer2 interface as recommended by MSDN.
ProcessVideoSample(VideoSample);

//I call IMFSourceReader to read the next available video sample. This method is thread safe. The sample reader is in Asynchronous mode.
RequestNextSample(TypeSample.Video);

//Delay to read the next sample. The delay is calculated as shown above.
await Task.Delay(DelayFrameRate);
```

In the case of audio, the process is the same, except that it calls the audio buffer.

The delay time here is a problem, I don't know the time I should implement. In several tests, I noticed that a delay over **16ms** starts to make squeaks in the audio playback. Therefore, the Audio delay I left as **15ms**.

I have tried to synchronize Audio processing with Video processing, I did not get a good result, the audio crashes too much during playback.

## 1 Update - 08/24/2019

I modified the code according to what **VuVirt** gave me, but unfortunately I was unsuccessful at some points.
Now I can keep Audio synchronized properly, because I'm rendering at the correct rendering time.
Unfortunately, the video did not follow the same process. It keeps crashing during playback, and as I suspected, if you use a delay it can display acceptably. Which makes me wonder, maybe the EVR isn't delaying what it should.

presentation time of the samples is correct as follows, then discarded the process that selects the samples.

[image: Image Debug Player]

Video samples are processed so quickly by EVR that the sample buffer does not track, in a test, I could not even get the ms time it took for EVR to render the buffer. Speed was below millisecond range

Below I have the code inside the task that is checking and requesting samples for the buffer:

```
//Variable that will contain the Stream type
StreamType Tp = StreamType.TP_Audio;

//wait for the presentation clock to start.
while (StatusPresentationClock != EnumStatusClock.Started)
{

}

// Create the loop that will be checking and ordering the samples.
while (VideoPlayer.Permission)
{
//Checks if the amount of audio buffer samples is below the total size.
if (BufferSamplesAudio.Count <= (LengthBuffer))
{
                            //Continue
}
else
{
//The buffer has the maximum number of samples. Even taking this delay, at various times evr renders faster.
await Task.Delay(1);
goto Done;
}

//Checks if the audio stream has not reached its end
if(VideoPlayer.EndStreamAudio)
{
//The audio stream is over
SendCon.Send("Audio Task", "Stream End!!");

//Exit
break;
}

//Defines that you are reading an audio sample
AudioRender.ReadingAudioSample = true;

//Calls the method that will request a sample from the reader.
ResultCode Result = RequestNewSample(Tp);

//Check call result
if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
{
//Call Exception
throw new Exception("ERROR");
}
                     
//Waits for the reading process to be completed.
while (AudioRender.ReadingAudioSample)
{
                           
}
                        
Done:;
}
```

Following is the code I used to create the EVR:

```
                //Calls the method for creating a Media Sink trigger that will be used to render the video.
                Result = CarenEVR.CreateInstanceVideoRender(SurfaceVideo.Handle, out VideoRender.AtivadorVideoSink);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Calls the method to create an instance of EVR.
                Result = VideoRender.ActivatorVideoSink.ActivateObject(InterfacesMediaFoundation.IID_IMFMediaSink, out ICarenQuery MediaSinkEVR);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Converts the interface to the MediaSink.
                VideoRender.VideoSinkRender = ConvertInterfaceBase<ICaren_MidiaSink>(ref MediaSinkEVR);

                //Get interface that represents the real video renderer
                Result = VideoRender.VideoSinkRender.QueryInterface(InterfacesMediaFoundation.IID_IVideoRenderer, out ICarenQuery OutInterfaceSolictada);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Convert interface to real video renderer
                VideoRender.EVR = ConvertInterfaceBase<ICaren_EVR>(ref OutInterfaceSolictada);

                //Initializes the video renderer in standard mode.
                Result = VideoRender.EVR.InitializeVideoRender(null, null);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Queries the service interface for the video renderer
                Result = VideoRender.EVR.QueryInterface(InterfacesMediaFoundation.IID_IMFGetService, out ICarenQuery OutInterfaceServico);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Converts and defines the interface.
                VideoRender.ServiceInterface = ConvertInterfaceBase<ICaren_ObterInterface>(ref OutInterfaceServico);

                //Calls the method to get the EVR from the service interface exposed by the video renderer.
                Result = VideoRender.ServiceInterface.GetService(MFServiceInterfaces.MR_VIDEO_RENDER_SERVICE, InterfacesMediaFoundation.IID_IMFVideoDisplayControl, out ICarenQuery OutInterfaceDisplayControl);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Converts and define the interface.
                VideoRender.VideoControler = ConvertInterfaceBase<ICaren_ControladorVideo>(ref OutInterfaceDisplayControl);

                //Defines the surface handle that will display the video frames.
                Result = VideoRender.VideoControler.SetHandleSurface(SufarceVideo.Handle);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Sets video window position
                Result = VideoRender.VideoControler.SetVideoPosition(null, new CA_Rectangle() { Rigth = SurfaceVideo.Width, Bottom = SurfaceVideo.Height });

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Get Direct3D Manager
                Result = VideoRender.VideoSinkRender.ConsultarServiceInterface(MFServiceInterfaces.MR_VIDEO_ACCELERATION_SERVICE, InterfacesDirectX.IID_IDirect3DDeviceManager9, out ICarenQuery OutInterfaceD3DManager);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Convert interface
                VideoRender.Direct3DManager = ConvertInterfaceBase<ICaren_Direct3DDeviceManager9>(ref OutInterfaceD3DManager);



                //Sets the presentation clock for the media source.

                //Defines the presentation clock that will be used by the player.
                Result = VideoRender.VideoSinkRender.SetPresentationClock(VideoPlayer.PresentationClock);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }



                //Configures the Media Stream Sink and the sample allocator.

                //Configures the Media Stream Sink and the sample allocator.
                Result = VideoRender.VideoSinkRender.GetStreamSinkByIndex(0, out VideoRender.StreamVideo);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }

                //Get media type handler
                Result = VideoRender.StreamVideo.GetMediaTypeHandle(out VideoRender.MediaTypeHandler);

                //Checks for no operation error
                if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
                {
                    //Exit Method
                    goto Done;
                }
```

The code for the presentation clock:

```
 //Create the presentation clock
            ResultCode Result = CarenPresentationClock.CreateIntance(out VideoPlayer.PresentationClock);

            //Check Result of Operation
            if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
            {
                //Get out of the method
                goto Done;
            }

            //Create time source for presentation clock
            Result = CarenPresentationClockSourceTime.CreateIntance(out VideoPlayer.SourcePresentationClock);

            //Check Result of Operation
            if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
            {
                //Get out of the method
                goto Done;
            }

            //Creates the status notification clock for the presentation clock.
            Result = CarenClockStateSink.CreateIntance(out VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock);

            //Check Result of Operation
            if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
            {
                //Get out of the method
                goto Done;
            }


            //Configures the clock events.
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.OnClockStart += NotificationPresentationClock_OnClockStart;
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.OnClockPause += NotificationPresentationClock_OnClockPause;
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.OnClockRestart += NotificationPresentationClock_OnClockRestart;
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.OnClockStop += NotificationPresentationClock_OnClockStop;
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.OnClockSetRate += NotificationPresentationClock_OnClockSetRate;

            //This method will log the events of the generated Clock in the native interface and send to managed code.
            VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock.RegisterCallback();


            //Sets the presentation clock.


            //Sets the clock time source in the presentation clock.
            Result = VideoPlayer.PresentationClock.SetSourceTime(VideoPlayer.SourcePresentationClock);

            //Check Result of Operation
            if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
            {
                //Get out of the method
                goto Done;
            }
       
            //Sets the notification clock.
            Result = VideoPlayer.PresentationClock.RegisterObjectNotification(VideoPlayer.NotificationPresentationClock);

            //Check Result of Operation
            if (Result != ResultCode.SS_OK)
            {
                //Get out of the method
                goto Done;
            }
            
        Done:;
            //Return the result
            return Result;
```

Note: I'm using DXVA2 for decoding acceleration in IMFSourceReader, could this have anything to do with video crashes during playback?

## 2 Update - 08/25/2019

The problem with Video crashing was because I was not using **IMFSinkWriter** to render Video samples. Looking at your information, I noticed that it prevents samples from being rendered too fast.
**But the video is still out of sync with Audio.**

Comment: You'll need separate threads and queues for audio and video processing. Each thread will wait for the time corresponding to the first sample in its queue and will send the sample to the renderer/writer when it is time for it.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I already have the threads for each stream and their corresponding sample queues. By the way you commented, you mean I have to use the values of (Duration and the sample presentation time obtained from the queue)? If so, should I implement a delay with the sample presentation time? I'm kind of lost yet. How will I process the sample at the time of presentation of the same?

Comment: Yes, you keep the samples in corresponding queues (the samples are reference counted and if the source uses some memory pool it might get blocked if too many samples are queued). You must have a producer thread for each queue and one consumer thread. The consumer thread polls the queues and finds the smallest presentation time sample from the queues. Then the consumer thread fetches that sample from its queue (removes it from the queue) and sends it to the rest of the pipeline (writer/renderer).

Comment: The renderers will properly delay each sample that is sent to them. You don’t need to delay it. Otherwise if you only use writers for muxing then you’ll need the samples to be processed as quickly as possible

Comment: Before making any changes to the code let me know if I understand. The (production) threads are like "Factory", they will be monitoring the amount of samples in their queues and will be requesting new ones for the reader (IMFSourceReader). The thread (Consumer) is like a "Client", it will look in both buffers (Audio and Video) which has the shortest presentation time and send it to the appropriate renderer (SAR or EVR), excluding it from the buffer from which it was obtained. Let me know if this is what you wanted to teach me!

Comment: Yes if by shortest you mean soonest

Comment: Please see the edit I made in my question. I implemented the system you taught me. Unfortunately, the video keeps crashing! :(

Comment: I don’t have time to look into your code in details but from a quick look I took I don’t think you implemented it exactly as I described it. I don’t see any threads and queues. Also you don’t have to limit the buffers yourself. The reference counting and memory pool will take care of it. I’ll need the complete code in order to help you further.

Comment: I am translating the Player code into English and I provide you. I solved the crash problem, it was because I wasn't using IMFSinkWriter to render the video. But it continues without synchronization with the audio.

Comment: This is the link you can use to access my OneDrive and view the code file.
Contains all the Threading scheme I am using and the rendering process.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Alv3Toc22kjtg8AbAg7OgeLdQ_DQIg?e=jv5bQV. Please take your time, I know it must be very busy.

Comment: I checked your code briefly and I think you could try to set LengthMaximumBuffer to a much bigger value, or you should remove the check if the queue has more than LengthMaximumBuffer packets. I also think that your synchronization problem might be due to the  Media Foundation .NET. I don't believe that Media Foundation should be utilized through .NET, due to performance reasons (data marshaling etc.). Media Foundation is meant for C++. IMO, it is much better if you implement all the Media Foundation Playback part in a C++/CLI dll and reference it from your C# app.

Comment: I do not use (Media Foundation .NET) available from SourceForge. I have my own API that I developed in C++/ CLI. About the buffer size you mentioned, I've tried the options and I was unsuccessful, in fact, the amount is not below 4 so fast it processes. I have the IMFMediaSession and MediaEngine interfaces that work very well in C#. I don't have (video rendering delay), on the contrary, it renders so quickly that audio is left behind. That's why I disregarded the marshaling time between C# and C++. I can be talking bullshit too. Thank you so much for your time on this issue !!